# Получить класс к которому прявязан элемент selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Можно ли как-то получить класс элемента, к которому привязан элемент?

К примеру

```
<div class="element">
   <li class="first_name"> Иван </li>
   <li class="second_name"> Иванов </li>
```

У меня есть элемент, который я нашел по классу "first_name", мне нужно получить класс "element"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ, нужно сделать так:

```
elem.find_element(By.XPATH, "..").get_attribute("class")
```